# Package to read Excel file (xlsx file) in R 3.3.0

Tags: r, excel, install.packages

With the new version of R, R 3.3.0, which came out in May, I can no longer read Excel or xlsx files using the package "XLSX." Has anyone found a new package that works with R 3.3.0 to read these file types?

Comment: `read.xlsx` keeps reading Excel files in my case, did you try updating the package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently in R3.3.0 and using the package `readxl` to load xlsx / xls files in to R and it's OK for me.

It could be a problem with your Java version. To load `xlsx` package, you need `rjava` package. Maybe your version of Java is not up to date.